Find $\int_0^\pi \frac{8 \, d \theta}{5+2 \cos \theta}$
Find $\int_0^\pi \frac{8 \, d \theta}{5+2 \cos \theta}$

Let $z = e^{i \theta}$. Then $dz = \frac{d \theta}{iz}$
\begin{align}
    \begin{split}
        8 \int_0^\pi \frac{\, d \theta}{5+2 \cos \theta} &= \int_1^{-1} \frac{1}{iz} \frac{\, dz}{5+2\left( \frac{z+z^{-1}}{2} \right)} \\
        &= \frac{1}{i} \int_1^{-1} \frac{1}{z} \cdot \frac{dz}{5+z+z^{-1}} \\
        &=\frac{1}{i} \int_1^{-1} \frac{dz}{z^2+6} \\
        &= \frac{1}{i} \int_1^{-1} \frac{dz}{(z-\sqrt{6}i)(z+\sqrt{6}i)} 
    \end{split}
\end{align}
Ideally, I would finish this problem by either a.) splitting this into partial fractions and doing Cauchy's Integral formula twice or b.) by using Residue Theorem for the above integral. That said, both of those tools require a closed curve $\gamma$. But the curve going from $1$ to $-1$ (analogously, from $0$ to $\pi$ at the start) is not a closed curve. What can I do here? Is there any way to re-interpret the integral with a closed curve?
EDIT: It’s been brought o my attention that I have an error above. It should say $dz= iz \hspace{0.1cm} d\theta$

Check your calculations. $8 \int_0^\pi \frac{, d \theta}{5+2 \cos \theta}$ is real, while $\frac{1}{i} \int_1^{-1} \frac{dz}{z^2+6}$ is not.

The integrand is even, you may use that to express the integral in the whole unit circle

Another way: convert cos to tan theta/2

Notice how
$$\int_0^\pi\frac{8}{5+2\cos\theta}\,\mathrm d\theta=\frac{1}{2}\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{8}{5+2\cos\theta}\,\mathrm d\theta$$
Now you'll be able to apply the same substitution $\gamma: z=e^{i\theta}\iff \mathrm dz
=iz\,\mathrm d\theta$ and have a closed contour:
$$\oint_\gamma\frac{4}{5+2\left(\dfrac{z+z^{-1}}{2}\right)}\,\frac{\mathrm dz}{iz}=-4i\oint_\gamma\frac{1}{z^2+5z+1}\,\mathrm dz=-4i\oint_\gamma\frac{1}{(z-z_1)(z-z_2)}\,\mathrm dz$$
where $z_1=-\dfrac{\sqrt{21}+5}{2}>1$ and $z_2=\dfrac{\sqrt{21}-5}{2}<1$.
Therefore we'll apply Cauchy's integral formula on $z_2$ which is the only pole lying in the contour $\gamma$. Thus,
$$-4i\oint_\gamma\frac{1/(z-z_1)}{z-z_2}\,\mathrm dz=-4i\cdot 2\pi i\left[\frac{1}{z-z_1}\right|_{z=z_2}=8\pi\dfrac{1}{\dfrac{\sqrt{21}-5}{2}+\dfrac{\sqrt{21}+5}{2}}=\frac{8\pi}{\sqrt{21}}$$
In conclusion,
$$\boxed{\int_0^\pi\frac{8}{5+2\cos\theta}\,\mathrm d\theta=\frac{8\pi}{\sqrt{21}}}$$

Exploiting the even symmetry of the cosine function, we see that
$$\begin{align}
I&=\int_0^\pi \frac{8}{5+2\cos(\theta)}\,d\theta\\\\
&=\frac12 \int_{-\pi}^\pi \frac{8}{5+2\cos(\theta)}\,d\theta\\\\
\end{align}$$
Now, we can make the substitution $z=e^{i\theta}$ so that
$$\begin{align}
I&=4 \int_{-\pi}^\pi \frac{1}{5+2\cos(\theta)}\,d\theta\\\\
&=4\oint_{|z|=1} \frac1{5+z+z^{-1}}\frac1{iz}\,dz\\\\
&=-4i\oint_{|z|=1} \frac1{z^2+5z+1}\,dz\\\\
&=-4i\oint_{|z|=1} \frac1{\left(z+\frac52+\frac{\sqrt{21}}{2}\right)\left(z+\frac52-\frac{\sqrt{21}}{2}\right)}\,dz\\\\
&=2\pi i (-4i)\text{Res}\left(\frac1{\left(z+\frac52+\frac{\sqrt{21}}{2}\right)\left(z+\frac52-\frac{\sqrt{21}}{2}\right)}, z=-\frac52+\frac{21}{2}\right)\\\\
&=\frac{8\pi}{\sqrt{21}}
\end{align}$$
And we are done!

Hi Mark ! Long time no speak. Are you OK ? Cheers

@ClaudeLeibovici Hi Claude!  It has been a while indeed.  I am doing OK.  How are you doing?
